# Find all ancestors of hierarchical data

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have the following table hat contains data structure with a hierarchy

```
+----+----------+-------------+
| ID | ParentID |  FullPath   |
+----+----------+-------------+
|  1 | NULL     | (1)         |
|  2 | 1        | (1)/(2)     |
|  3 | 2        | (1)/(2)/(3) |
|  4 | NULL     | (4)         |
|  5 | 4        | (4)/(5)     |
|  6 | 4        | (4)/(6)     |
|  7 | 6        | (4)/(6)/(7) |
+----+----------+-------------+
```

How can I retrieve the ancestors of an item ?
For example, if I'm looking for the ancestors of ID 3, I would get 1 and 2.
Likewise, if I'm looking for 7, I would get 4 and 6 (note 5 is not there).

I know I can avoid using CTE with the FullPath by parsing the column and using Dynamic SQL, but I'm having a hard time creating the query.

EDIT:
I want a query that will let me get every ancestor row of an item. For example, if I want the ancestors of 7, the query would return the following table:

```
+----+----------+-------------+
| ID | ParentID |  FullPath   |
+----+----------+-------------+
|  4 | NULL     | (4)         |
|  6 | 4        | (4)/(6)     |
+----+----------+-------------+
```

The reason is because I have more columns that describe the item and I need to fetch them and compare them.

Comment: Why do you need dynamic SQL for this? Is the above a `hierachyid`? If so, have you have a look at it's documentation? If not, why isn't it one, when it's structured very simular to one.

Comment: It is not hierarchyid type, and it isn't because that possibility was not analysed before the conception of the solution. I'm thinking of using dynamic SQL since I can parse the path to have csv data, and then input it in an `IN` operator

Comment: Do you use HierarchyId Transact's SQL Type or your own datatype (like chars...) ? In HierarchyId  the method GetAncestor() will give you the answer.

Comment: FullPath column is a `varchar(1028)` at the moment, so we cannot use GetAncestor. I'm aware HierarchyID has functions that do what I need to do, but it is not possible to implement it in our situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a full path as part of your data, why not parse the ancestors out of it? No dynamic SQL or CTE required with `string_split()`.

**Sample data**

```
declare @Data table
(
    ID int,
    ParentID int,
    FullPath nvarchar(50)
);

insert into @Data (ID, ParentID, FullPath) values
(1, NULL, '(1)'         ),
(2, 1   , '(1)/(2)'     ),
(3, 2   , '(1)/(2)/(3)' ),
(4, NULL, '(4)'         ),
(5, 4   , '(4)/(5)'     ),
(6, 4   , '(4)/(6)'     ),
(7, 6   , '(4)/(6)/(7)' );
```

**Solution**

```
select  d.ID as SelectedID,
        da.*
from @Data d
cross apply string_split(d.FullPath, '/') s
join @Data da -- data ancestor
    on da.ID = convert(int, replace(replace(s.value, '(', ''), ')', ''))
where d.ID = 7
  and d.ID <> da.ID -- filter out ID itself
order by d.ID, da.ID;
```

**Result**

```
SelectedID  ID          ParentID    FullPath
----------- ----------- ----------- -------------
7           4           NULL        (4)
7           6           4           (4)/(6)
```

Comment: That will give the previous ancestor, I however need the list of every single direct ancestor.

Comment: Looks like your question needs an update then... This solution gives exactly what you described: 3=>1&2, 7=>4&6. Perhaps add your expected output result/format to the question.

Comment: Nice thank you ! Gotta love the `CROSS APPLY` magic ;)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a self-join: -

```
DECLARE   @Hierarchy TABLE
        (
          ID        int PRIMARY KEY
        , ParentID  int
          -- Non-clustered index key can be up to 1600 bytes on SQL 2016+
        , FullPath  varchar(1028) UNIQUE
        )
;
INSERT    @Hierarchy
        ( ID, ParentID, FullPath )
VALUES
        ( 1, NULL, '(1)' )
,       ( 2, 1   , '(1)/(2)' )
,       ( 3, 2   , '(1)/(2)/(3)' )
,       ( 4, NULL, '(4)' )
,       ( 5, 4   , '(4)/(5)' )
,       ( 6, 4   , '(4)/(6)' )
,       ( 7, 6   , '(4)/(6)/(7)' )
;
SELECT    N.ID
        , A.ID
        , A.ParentID
        , A.FullPath
FROM      @Hierarchy AS N
          INNER JOIN @Hierarchy AS A ON N.FullPath LIKE A.FullPath + '%'
WHERE     N.ID <> A.ID
ORDER BY  N.ID ASC
        , A.ID ASC
;
```

In my test the above query does use the unique index on FullPath. This is an alternative but it does full scans rather than use the index: -

```
SELECT    N.ID
        , A.ID
        , A.ParentID
        , A.FullPath
FROM      @Hierarchy AS N
          INNER JOIN @Hierarchy AS A ON SUBSTRING(N.FullPath, 1, LEN(A.FullPath)) = A.FullPath 
WHERE     N.ID <> A.ID
ORDER BY  N.ID ASC
        , A.ID ASC
;
```